# Transform structure XML to flat XML except some columns

Tags: c#, xml, sqlite

I have exported a SQLite database to structure XML, then transformed it to flat XML using following code in c#.net.

```
XDocument Doc = XDocument.Load("myXML.xml");
            XElement[] elements = Doc.DescendantNodes()
                .Where(n => n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text).Select(n => n.Parent).ToArray(); 

            foreach (XElement element in elements)
            {
                element.Parent.SetAttributeValue(element.Name, element.Value);
                element.Remove();
            }
```

the structure XML was like following

```
<apple>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Apple 1</name>
      <orange>
        <id>5</id>
        <orangeNmae>C1</orangeNmae>
        <function>good for health</function>
        <part>7</part>
        <banana>
          <id>9</id>
          <bananaName>48</bananaName>
          <effect>23</effect>         
          <notes>be careful</notes>
        </banana>
        <banana>
          <id>10</id>
          <bananaName>49</bananaName>
          <effect>24</effect>         
          <notes>be careful!</notes>        
        </banana>
      </orange>
</apple>
```

the generated flat xml was like following

```
<apple id="1" name="Apple 1">
      <orange id="5" orangeNmae="C1" function="good for health" part="7">        
        <banana id="9" bananaName="48" effect="23" notes="be careful" />
        <banana id="10" bananaName="49" effect="24" notes="be careful" />        
      </orange>
</apple>
```

Now I need to keep some columns like structured XML like following

```
<apple id="1" name="Apple 1">
      <orange id="5" orangeNmae="C1" function="good for health" part="7">        
        <banana id="9" bananaName="48" />               
          <notes>be careful</notes>
          <effect>23</effect>
        <banana id="10" bananaName="49" />                   
          <notes>be careful</notes>
          <effect>23</effect>       
      </orange>
</apple>
```

Could anyone give me any hints how to do that ?
Should I change my approach while transforming the structured XML to flat XML ?

Comment: Wouldn't an XSLT transformation be a better fit for this?

Comment: could you please give me any example ?

Comment: is there any way to skip some columns from transformation to flat xml ?

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT does the transformation for you. I used templates to match the elements and use the mode capabilities of the XSLT processor to first handle the transdormation to attributes and after that handle the other elements.

```
  <!-- elements to be transformed to attributes -->
  <xsl:template match="*[not(text()[normalize-space()])]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="attr"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- copy elements not handled as attribute -->
  <xsl:template match="effect|notes">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- create attributes excluding certain elements -->
  <xsl:template match="*[text()[normalize-space()] and not(self::effect | self::notes)]" mode="attr">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- surpress defaults -->
  <xsl:template match="text()">
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*|text()" mode="attr">
  </xsl:template>
```

And here is how you could leverage that:

```
        var xct = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xct.Load(XmlReader.Create("transform.xslt"));
        var xw = XmlWriter.Create("output.xml"));
        xct.Transform(
           XmlReader.Create("input.xml"),
           xw);
```